# javascript document.getElementsbyClassName is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make function that searches my page for classes `ardiv` and then search these classes for class with name `hiddenid` but i am still getting error

> document.getElementsbyClassName is not a function.

I have read many articles with same error but no solution helped me.

Here is my code:

```
function hledat() {

var divs = document.getElementsbyClassName("ardiv");

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var para = divs[i].getElementsbyClassName( "hiddenid" ).value;
    alert( para );
}

}

hledat();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be `document.getElementsByClassName`
(the "B" is the difference)